# Using UML for agile development

Tags: uml

I had some confusing questions while I was reading
"UML Distilled by Martin Fowler ."

## Question 1.

In this book, it mentioned that:

> The three ways of using UML: sketch、blueprint, and programming language.

Our professor, demanded us to draw "**all**" of the class and operation, and then develop it, while we are doing System analysis & Design.

Thus, I really wonder if it is what martin said "pseudoiterative development" or not.

It’s use UML by “blueprint”?

## Question 2.

In this book, it mentioned that:

> "Each iteration doesn't start from scratch;
>
> rather, it modifies the existing body of documents, highlighting the changes in the new iteration."

However, the professor asked us to modify and adding more classes to **existing** class diagram each iteration of dev.

Take Design Class Diagram as example. In the first stage, we only have very little "class," but the professor asked us to keep adding it.

[first stage class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfAro.png)

What's worse, in this way, to the last stage, class becomes too much and even couldn't be understood, nor will be used to communicate (as the picture).

[tenth stage class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkumv.jpg)

Therefore, I am quite confused if the professor misunderstands the meaning of "modifies the existing body of documents”?

If what the professor taught us is not right," how and **when** could "modifies the existing body of documents" be used? Is there only related class diagram?

Thanks.

Comment: Well we don't actually know if the teacher failed to mention about packages or OP failed to catch/understand when a teacher was talking about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1

Yes, it's a use as a blueprint.

### Q2

Your professor understands correctly.

Just as a book says you start with a limited scope only only some of the classes. In further iterations you use what you've created so far and add more classes, attributes and operations as needed due to increasing complexity of your system. Sometimes you need to rethink and somewhat remodel/redesign (and then take the code!) of what you've already created. That's exactly what agile is about.

What you might be missing is that you don't need to put whole system on a single diagram. Use packages to organize your classes (and use package diagram as a sort of table of contents for your project). Split your single diagram into smaller chunks focusing on elements concentrated around specific topics (those will more or less reflect your packages). Show all details of a class only on its "main" diagram (the one that presents a package containing this class) and on other diagrams put just class rectangle with a class name and eventually the attributes and operations needed for the particular relationships if your modelling tool supports that.

As you'll often build scope by specific areas you'll see that you'll be mostly creating new packages and the existing one will only have small changes (except packages like `Tools`. Then you'll know that you're following the right path.

Comment: Thank you! It’s clear.  
But the question for now is that how should I use design class diagram on 10th stage.  
As you said, Only focusing on elements concentrated around specific topics?
Sorry for my poor concept ...

Comment: First you need to understand that your model will consist of several class diagrams. In other words you'll need to see all diagrams to understand the whole application. In each iteration you'll modify the model as a whole. It means that in iteration you can do any of the following (and usually you'll be doing more than one of those on each iteration): add new diagram and new classes in it, add classes, class details and relationships to any off already existing diagrams, change some logic ibn already existing diagrams, exclude some class from existing into a new diagram.

Comment: Each iteration will have its scope (focus) and usually (but not necessarily) it'll be based on a specific topic (or topics). And you'll need to show what have changed in the iteration - what packages, classes, features and relationships were added or changed so that one could write code changes based on that. Note that if your diagram now consists of lets say 80 classes after 10 iterations, your model will also contain 80 unique classes on all diagrams (however some classes might be shown on more than one diagram). The difference is that they are nicely organized in several smaller diagrams.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I understand finally.
But I wanna check that my understand whether correctly:"If I have package A, B, C.  So I maybe have 3 class diagrams to talk about them, and modify, mark-change them on each iteration rather than create new diagram" ?

Comment: You change class diagrams you have but if you discover a need for a new package then you can create new packages/new diagrams as well. Treat whole model (all classes and relationship) as your base that have some modifications in each iteration. If you show the changes on existing diagrams or create a new one will depend on what changes you apply to the model.
In other words it might be that in Iteation 1 you'll create diagrams A, B and C with one class diagram for each of them. Then in iterations 2 and 3 only change them. But in iteration 4 you add package D with ne class diagram etc.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed answer to your questions would take us too far apart.

1. Theoretically yes. But practically you would use UML only for the first two steps. Once it was an idea to use UML also for programming, but honestly, programming languages are much better for that. Keep UML to some abstract level. Get concrete when programming. And find ways to not create too wide fissures between both. Blueprint is just a more concrete than sketch, but a still abstract way towards to final program.

   You could use UML for programming by placing behavior inside operations. This would usually be just plain program code. State machines can as well be translated to target code. There's also executable UML, but I have no plan about that. Just google if you're curious.
2. Iteration indeed starts at some existing previous version. But now you have many ways leading you to Rome. Modeling as-is and to-be is a difficult task with and without UML modeling tools. You need to decide on a rule set that allows for reaching the next step from the current one. You can do this by introducing version numbers and/or stereotypes. Very complex. Anyhow, the 10th stage you picture does not show any development, only addition. You need to find structures. Packages are one way to achieve structure.  And you shall not end up with a single large class diagram, but a couple for each sub-domain.

   What you do in a normal design is to create sub-domains that deal with individual parts of the system (e.g. I/O, UI, persistence, etc.). Now you can make packages for these sub-domains and you will create class diagrams along with them. Additionally you create diagrams that show how the packages and the classes inside relate to each other. Here you will use package and class diagrams. Note that UML is not about diagramming. The diagrams are just means to show humans how the whole model is constructed.

Comment: Thank you!! but still have some question ><
1. Can you give me example or concept that UML using for programming? In the book, it's not  clear.
2.As you said: "you shall not end up with a single large class diagram".So how can I make design class diagram in the 10th stage? Only focusing on main topic?

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I understand finally.
But I wanna check that my understand whether correctly:"If I have package A, B, C.  So I maybe have 3 class diagrams to talk about them, and modify, mark-change them on each iteration rather than create new diagram" ?

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't grows at one place only.